# Why we need Event Emitter in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
const events = require("events")
const eventEmitter = new events.EventEmitter()

function hi(){
    console.log("sa")
}

eventEmitter.on("say_hi",hi)
eventEmitter.emit("say_hi")
```

Why i need event emitter for run the function? I can run function with just `funcName();`
Why I should use it?

Comment: Why do you need a function at all? You can just run `console.log("sa")` directly.

Comment: @Bergi your question is meanless. Functions are important

Comment: And so are event emitters for [pub/sub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish–subscribe_pattern) :-) Maybe just not in this particular example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you build a library or internal API, it allows other parts of your code (or people using your code) to subscribe to events without you needing to know this in advance.

For the case you used it above, it does not make sense.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/70043049